# Inferring implemented type from generic base

Tags: c#, generics

Disclaimer: I am quite unsure of the terminology surrounding generics. Perhaps this is why I am not finding a solution by searching.

#### Context

Using .Net's built-in DI-container, I need to extract and inject a bunch of `IEntity` getters from a bunch of `Repository<T>` where `T: IEntity`.
E.g. `Foo: IEntity` and `FooRepository: RepositoryBase<Foo>`.

To save some typing, I have a

```cs
public delegate Task<T> Get<T>(Guid id);
```

In my `program.cs` I have bunch of these:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Get<Foo>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<FooRepository>().Get);
```

This works fine, but I am trying to write this in a more concise manner.

The best I have been able to do is:

```cs
static Get<TEntity> From<TRepo, TEntity>(IServiceProvider services)
    where TRepo : RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
=> services.GetRequiredService<TRepo>().Get;
```

which I can then use like so:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Get<Foo>>(From<FooRepository, Foo>);
```

I am not sure this is an improvement, since I now have repeated references to `Foo`.
Also, Rider is telling me that indeed `<Get<Foo>>` is redundant and can be removed. Doing so works and gets rid of the redundant type reference, but is a big step down in readability.

I naïvely tried just removing the second type parameter, hoping that the typesystem could infer TEntity from usages of `From`, but this does not work ("Cannot resolve symbol TEntity") and I cannot remove it entirely, since RepositoryBase is then missing T, and without RepositoryBase, TRepo does not contain a `Get`:

```cs
static Get<TEntity> From<TRepo>(IServiceProvider services)
    where TRepo : RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
=> services.GetRequiredService<TRepo>().Get;
```

#### Question(s):

**Is there a way of delaying inference of `TEntity` to usage, or declaring it as "the type parameter `T` which the non-generic `TRepo` uses to implement `RepositoryBase<T>`"?**

Or more broadly, since I suspect this could be an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/):

**How to write `From` to allow a usage such as this?:**

```cs
services.AddScoped<Get<Foo>>(From<FooRepository>);
```

Comment: See answer below for solution option w/ non-generic `Repository` which will (1) reduce generic closures - increasing performance and (2) simplify dependency injection - automatically wiring any constructor of type `Repository`, etc.

Comment: The repositories are provided to me as is. Also, their implementations vary quite a lot by TEntity.

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically simply your implementation by using a single non-generic repository class with generic method calls (e.g. `Repository.Get<MyEntity>()`.

See below for a working example.  Note, that in the example I'm using a generic entity Id (`TKey`).  You can remove this if your committing to a single id type (e.g. long, Guid).

```
// Extension method that registers the repo
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRepositories(this IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
}

// Example Usage in Startup.cs (or Program.cs)
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   => services.AddRepositories();

//Example usage - note -now just register repo and DI will wire up ctors
var repo = services.GetRequiredService<Repository>();
var entity = repo.Get<Foo>(x => x.Id == 1234);
var entities = repo.GetAll<Foo>().Where(x => x.Prop1 > blah).ToList();


//////////////////////////MOCK IMPLEMENTATION///////////

// ENTITY
public interface IEntity<TKey>
   where TKey : unmanaged
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo: IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// REPOSITORY
public interface IRepository 
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class;

    TEntity Get<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate) where TEntity : class;

    Task<TEntity> GetAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class;

}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    DbContext _dbContext;
    public Repository(DbContext context) => _dbContext = context;

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
    => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate)!;

    public TEntity Get<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate) where TEntity : class
    => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate)!;

    public Task<TEntity> GetAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
    => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate)!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to use DI for generic types would be;

```cs
public interface IRepository<T>{
    Task<T> Get(Guid id);
}
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> { ... }
public class FooRepository : RepositoryBase<Foo> { ... }

services.AddScoped<IRepository<Foo>,FooRepository>();

public class Something{
    public Something(IRepository<Foo> repository){...}
}
```

Sure, the consumer of your service now needs the entire interface, rather than just the `Get` delegate. But this has much lower code complexity, and runtime overheads.

Then if you want to register separate services for different aspects of your repositories, but without the over head of allocating multiple instances;

```cs
public interface IGetRepository<T>{
    Task<T> Get(Guid id);
}
public interface IPutRepository<T>{
    Task Put(T);
}

public class RepositoryBase<T> : IGetRepository<T>, IPutRepository<T> { ... }

services.AddScoped<FooRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IGetRepository<Foo>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<FooRepository>());
services.AddScoped<IPutRepository<Foo>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<FooRepository>());
```

With a helper method to register each repository. Or by scanning the types in your assembly to auto-register all repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the How to write From question.

But you have to modify other things too:

```cs
    public delegate Task<T> Get<T>(Guid id);

    public class Foo
    {
    }

    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        Task<T> Get(Guid id);
    }

    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    {
        public abstract Task<T> Get(Guid id);
    }

    public class FooRepository : Repository<Foo>
    {
        public override async Task<Foo> Get(Guid id)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
            return new Foo();
        }
    }

    public void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<Foo>, FooRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<Get<Foo>>(From<Foo>);
    }

    public static Get<T> From<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        return provider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<T>>().Get;
    }
```

But you end up with a pretty clean From.

You may have issues, if missing repositories for some T.

However, the usual way is to just inject the repository and call it directly.